# Find the approximation with Gamma function

Tags: approximation

Let $n$ postive integer,Assmue that $\Gamma(x)$ is [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)}=A+\dfrac{B}{n}+\dfrac{C}{n^2}+\dfrac{D}{n^3}+\cdots$$

use $$\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\ln{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+z\right)}-\ln{\Gamma\left(1+z\right)}\right)=\varepsilon(z+1/2)-\varepsilon(z+1)$$
where $\varepsilon(z)$ is [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
Now I have prove 
$$A=\sqrt{\pi},B=-\sqrt{\pi}\log{2}$$
But can't find $C,D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$A(z)=\log(Y(z))=\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)\right)-\log (\Gamma (z+1))$$ you are looking for the Taylor expansion built around $z=0$. This means $$A(z)= A(0)+\frac{A'(0)} {1!}z+\frac{A''(0)} {2!}z^2+\frac{A'''(0)} {3!}z^3+\cdots$$

You are given for the derivatives 
$$A'(z)=\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}(z+1)$$ 
which generalizes to 
$$A''(z)=\psi ^{(1)}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}(z+1)$$ 
$$A'''(z)=\psi ^{(2)}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(2)}(z+1)$$

which, now, need to be simplified using $z=0$.

So $$A(0)=\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}\qquad A'(0)=-\log (4)\qquad A''(0)=\frac{\pi ^2}{3}\qquad A'''(0)=-12 \zeta (3)$$ This makes $$A(z)=\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}-\log (4)z+\frac{\pi ^2 }{6}z^2-2  \zeta
   (3)z^3+O\left(z^4\right)$$ Now, Taylor again $$Y(z)=e^{A(z)}=\sqrt{\pi }-\sqrt{\pi }  \log (4)z+\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\pi }  \left(\pi ^2+3 \log
   ^2(4)\right)z^2-\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{\pi } \left(12 \zeta (3)+\log ^3(4)+\pi
   ^2 \log (4)\right)\right)z^3 +O\left(z^4\right)$$ Now, to finish, replace $z$ by $\frac 1 {2n}$.

Just to see how accurate is the expansion,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation}\\
 5 & 1.565345082 & 1.563836840 \\
 10 & 1.660110105 & 1.660007284 \\
 15 & 1.695365291 & 1.695344347 \\
 20 & 1.713776688 & 1.713769957
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Google search for
"gamma function asymptotics"
leads to a number of
relevant links including this:

http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11

This, in turn,
has a number of references.
This one is free:

T. Burić and N. Elezović (2011) Bernoulli polynomials and asymptotic expansions of the quotient of gamma functions. J. Comput. Appl. Math. 235 (11), pp. 3315–3331.

It is available at

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042711000562